# Batch compress a folder of videos using handbrake (or other) - Without manually loading each video into the queue

Tags: compression

Ive got c.50 videos in `QuickTime movie` format. These video sit all in one folder on my computer. In the past when Ive had 5 or so files, ive imported them each into Handbrake, then saved them to the queue and run the queue.

But this is quite a tedious process as each one takes c. 1 min to import and save to que.

Is there a way to be able to point Handbrake (or any other video compression software) to a folder and tell it to compress all videos in that folder.

Im only tying to compress the videos, dont need to run any other processes on them.

Im doing this on a 2.7gz, 16gb ram macbook pro, but i also have Bootcamp so if the solution is only available on Windows i could run it there.

Comment: The Handbrake docs, and even the Handbrake UI, make it clear that batch processing an entire folder is supported. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

I use HandBrakeBatch for doing the same thing on Tv series or shows that have been downloaded, quite easy to use and can point it to a folder which has folder inside and it will batch them all choosing a preset of your choice

http://www.osomac.com/apps/osx/handbrake-batch/